# Im losing elements in my dynamically allocated arrays

Tags: c++, data-structures

Im implementing a stack which allocates a new array when the current array is full. It uses a linked list to keep the addresses of these arrays. When the stack `pop()`s the only element in an array, it deletes the array, deletes the linked list node which contains this array's address, then reverts to the next node (which is now in the front) and uses the array address within the node as its new "current array"

This is not working and I cannot change the basic structural requirement. The array deletes successfully, the node deletes successfully but for some reason, the old array seems to contain no data anymore and the function generally just breaks. Is there anything you can spot in these function definitions which obviously is the problem?:

Here the members (minus function prototypes and full LL def):

```cpp
class Stack
{
    private:
        int height;
        class LL
                {
                 ...
                }
        LL stack_map;
        string * current_stack;
    public:
        int top_element;
```

Constructor:

```cpp
Stack::Stack(int size)
{
    height = size;
    top_element = 0;

    current_stack = new string[height];

    stack_map.push_front(current_stack);
}
```

Push function:

```
void Stack::push(string data)
{
    if (top_element == height)
    {
        current_stack = new string[height];
        stack_map.push_front(current_stack);


        current_stack[0] = data;
        top_element = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        current_stack[top_element] = data;
        top_element++;
    }
}
```

And pop functions

```
bool Stack::pop(string& result_box)
{
    if (top_element == 0) 
    {


            delete[] current_stack;
            cout << "Array deleted" << endl;
            stack_map.delete_front(current_stack);
            cout << "number of nodes :" << stack_map.list_length() << endl;
            top_element = height - 1;
            cout << current_stack[top_element];
            result_box = current_stack[top_element];
            return true;

    }
    else
    {
        top_element--;
        result_box = current_stack[top_element];
        return true;
    }
}
```

Lastly here is the push_front and delete_front functions called in these:

push:

```
void push_front(string * current_stack)
                    {
                        LLnode * new_node;
                        new_node = new LLnode;
                        new_node -> stack_address = current_stack;

                        if (header == nullptr)
                        {
                            header = new_node;
                            new_node -> fwdPtr = nullptr;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            LLnode * temp;
                            temp = header;
                            header = new_node;
                            new_node -> fwdPtr = temp;
                        }

                        return;
                    }
```

delete:

```
                    void delete_front(string * current_stack)
                    {
                        LLnode * temp, * kill_box;

                        if (header == nullptr)
                        {
                            return;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            kill_box = header;
                            temp = header -> fwdPtr;
                            delete kill_box;
                            header = temp;
                            current_stack = temp -> stack_address;
                        }
                    }
```

I know this is a horrendous amount of code, I just dont understand the problem enough to minimize it further. Im not receiving errors, but my testing is not able to retrieve any strings once the `pop()` function tries to move back to a previous node/array.

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: I have a couple random `cout`s which I was using for testing purposes inside `pop()` , which can be ignored

Comment: Here's some advice: [edit] your question so that meets all requirements of a [mre], as explained in stackoverflow.com's [help], that anyone can cut/paste, compile, run, and reproduce your problem themselves. Otherwise it is unlikely that anyone will be able to help you.

Comment: `pop()` continues to return `true` after processing a `top_element == 0` instance but cannot place anything inside `result_box`

Comment: @SamVarshavchik ok, I will try to figure out how to reduce this, I'm not sure as I need to include all the parts. Perhaps doing so will help me figure it out on my own anyways. Thank you

Comment: The true beauty of the [mcve] is it's hard to produce one without spotting and fixing the bug yourself.As you reduce the amount of space the bug has to hide in, it becomes more obvious. Usually you only have to go a couple rounds of reducing before cursing, fixing and moving on to the next bug. And if you reduce down to a program down to nothing but bug and still can't solve it, you probably have a question that's worth recording here.

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately I found the bug. The function `delete_front()`, which is responsible for changing the `string * current_stack` pointer was passed by value and not by reference. Therefore, it was never pointing at anything but the already-deleted array.

This is why it appeared like I was "losing data", my pointer was always pointing at the deleted array instead of changing as node/arrays were deleted. I was so pleased when I found this. Maybe this can help someone in the future, it definitely will be a good reference for me.